# Is char s[] = {"ABC"}; legal?

Tags: arrays, c, declaration, string-literals, list-initialization

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    char s[] = {"hello"};
    printf("%s", s);
    return 0;
}
```

This code can be compiled and executed successfully,but how can one dimension array(char[] s) be assigned as the two dimension array({"hello"})?

Comment: It's not a "two dimension array" you use for initializer. The compiler will simply treat it as `char s[] = "hello";`

Answer (score 5):

It only works when there is only one string in the list. For example, this code fails to compile:

```c
char a[] = {"Hello", "World"};
printf("%s", a);
```

The compiler ignores the list when `a` is one-dimensional (your case) and there is only one string in the list. It's pretty much like this:

```c
char a[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
```

In fact, it doesn't have to be a string. These are also valid:

```c
int a = {7}; // a = 7
double b = {3.4}; // b = 3.4
```

If you want to make it two-dimensional (one dimension for strings and one dimension for the list itself):

```c
char *a[] = {"Hello"};
```

Or if you know your string size is fixed:

```c
char a[][6] = {"Hello"};
```

Answer (score 3):

C 2018 6.7.9 14 says:

> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF–8 string literal, optionally enclosed in braces…

`{"hello"}` is a string literal enclosed in braces.

Answer (score 1):

From the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 14 An array of character type may be initialized by a character string
> literal or UTF–8 string literal, **optionally enclosed in braces**.
> Successive bytes of the string literal (including the terminating null
> character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size)
> initialize the elements of the array.

Thus these two declarations of a character array

```
char s[] = {"hello"};
```

and

```
char s[] = "hello";
```

are equivalent.

Moreover you may also enclose in braces an initializing expression for a scalar object

> 11 **The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression,
> optionally enclosed in braces.** The initial value of the object is
> that of the expression (after conversion); the same type constraints
> and conversions as for simple assignment apply, taking the type of the
> scalar to be the unqualified version of its declared type.

So you may write for example either

```
char *s = "hello";
```

or

```
char *s = { "hello" };
```

or similarly

```
int x = 10;
```

or

```
int x = { 10 };
```

Note: in these declarations

```
char *s = "hello";
```

and

```
char *s = { "hello" };
```

the string literal having array type `char[6]` is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element of the type `char *`. Pointers are scalar types.

And one more remark. According to the C grammar you may append a comma to an initalizing list.

```
initializer:
    assignment-expression
    { initializer-list }
    { initializer-list , }
                      ^^^
```

That is you may write for example

```
char s[] = { "Hello " "Word", };
int x = { 10, };
```

Here is a demonstration program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    char s[] = { "Hello " "Word", };
    int x = { 10, };

    printf( "s = %s\n", s );
    printf( "x = %d\n", x );
}
```

The program output is

```
s = Hello Word
x = 10
```

Relative to this declaration

```
char s[] = { "Hello " "Word", };
```

pay attention to that according to the C Standard (5.1.1.2 Translation phases)

> 6. Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated.

That is the above declaration is equivalent to

```
char s[] = { "Hello Word", };
```

Bear in mind that there is an essential difference between C and C++ in the initialization of a character array with a string literal.
In C you may write for example

```
char s[5] = "hello";
```

In this case the array `s` will not contain a string because it has no room for storing the terminating zero character `'\0'` of the string literal.

In C++ such a declaration is invalid and will not compile.